# Customize "Done" button styling on Honeycomb Action Bar

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Looking to customize the "Done" button (height, background and text colors) in the top left of the action bar when items in a list have been checked. The green style applied with the HTC Jetstream isn't what I would like.

Where would I need to apply the style I need?